# Read .txt file in .c file for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, io

**Background**

I'm working on an app that calls a library my company has written previously in (plain) C.  The main part of my app is written in Obj-C.  At one point in the C code, the library needs to open and read data from a .txt file.  The .txt file will be created by the Obj-C in the main part of the app.

---

**The Issue**

I can't get the C code to find the .txt file.  Specifically, when i try to `fopen` the file and assign it to a `FILE` variable, the variable is always `NULL`.  Right now, the file is being written to the Documents folder of my app (but if that's the problem then I can change it).  I've enabled file sharing, so I was able to verify with iTunes that the file is being written correctly and exists in the Documents folder.

---

**My Attempts**

Here's some of the code I've attempted so far.

In App:

```
NSURL *docs = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
const char *dir = [docs UTF8String];
myLibraryEntryPoint(dir,(int)[docs length]);
```

In Library:

```
char *new_str;
if ((new_str = malloc(strlen(directory)+strlen("/myFile.txt")+1)) != NULL)
{
    new_str[0] = '\0';
    strcat(new_str,directory);
    strcat(new_str,"/myFile.txt");
}
else
{
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed!");
}
FILE *fp=fopen(new_str, "r");
```

I've also tried the following in the library:

```
FILE *fp=fopen("Documents/myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("/Documents/myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("/myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("Documents\myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("Documents\\myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("\Documents\myFile.txt", "r");
FILE *fp=fopen("\\Documents\\myFile.txt", "r");
```

As I said above, `fp` is always `NULL` after each of these attempts.  **What is the correct syntax in c to open a file in an iOS environment?**  I haven't made any changes in my Build Settings for my project to change the working directory, as covered [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877635/my-c-program-reads-a-text-file-when-i-put-it-into-xcode-it-fails-whats-happen) [all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438393/new-to-xcode-cant-open-files-in-c) [of these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476655/code-runs-perfect-in-g-but-not-in-xcode-cannot-find-file/14478210#14478210) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121752/opening-a-file-in-c-programming-in-xcode), because unlike those questions, my app is creating the .txt file itself.

---

**Resolution**

Turns out file paths are case sensitive.  My library was looking for `myFile.TXT`, where my app was writing to `myFile.txt`.  FML.

I'm going to leave this question here, because I think there's some good information in the comments and the suggested answers about file path syntax and how the current directory is handled by the library.  That information could be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Since you're handling relative paths, could you try to print the current directory? `puts(getcwd());` IIRC.

Comment: Don't trial&error, but use a debugger and use an absolute path to the file. `/myFile.txt` is an absolute path, but most likely not the one the file is located! And provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: I should put `puts(getcwd());` in my C code library, right?  If i just type that line, it throws a compiler error - the `getcwd` part doesn't show up in the autocomplete, so I wonder if that isn't supported?

Comment: Try that with the include line: `#include <unistd.h>
char *getcwd(char *buf, size_t size);` But maybe it's not supported.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yep, I needed that include line - thanks.  It just prints out `/`.  So that means the working directory **isn't** the directory where my app is installed, so all the relative paths I tried won't work, correct?

Comment: @GeneralMike: yes, it seems that your process starts with root dir as current directory. You have to chdir to your app directory or provide the full absolute path to it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, @Olaf: so the leading `\ ` makes it an absolute path in C?  Good to know.  In that case, the first example I provided in `My Attempts` should be sending a `char[]` with the absolute path into the library, and using that to try to open the file - it still doesn't work though.  I'll focus on that option then.

Comment: not `\\`, `/`. you're on unix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to `Documents`directory is accessible like this in objective-C:

```
NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
```

When using such a NSString path in C, you have to convert your NSString to UTF8 string:

```
NSString *fullPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile.txt"];
File *f = fopen(fullPath.UTF8String, "r");
```

Be aware that `fopen()` C function need to be passed the absolute path to the desired file to be able to open it.

If `fopen()` returns NULL, you can check what went wrong by checking `errno` for the error number and `strerror()` function (from ) to have a human readable explanation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

File *fileHandler = fopen( fullPathToFileAsUTF8String, openMode );
if( fileHandler == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File open error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as what I'm doing in the first part I listed under `My Attempts`?  And the library is a .c file, which means I can't have any obj-c code in that file.

Comment: C string is not the same as UT8 string.

Comment: I'm using `UTF8String`.  I tried using `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, doesn't look like it changed anything.

Comment: So, perhaps your file created by your application is not closed. Try to open a file that you created by hand using iTunes File Sharing.

Comment: That was a good idea.  I copied the file, added a `2` to the end of the name, put it back in with iTunes, and changed the code in just the library to look for the `2` file, but it still didn't find it.

Comment: Can you copy here a full path to the file as computed by your program?

Comment: And you can use C `errno` variable and `strerror()`function to get the error message corresponding to the last call of `fopen()` : `strerror(errno)`

Comment: Turns out it wasn't working for me because of a typo.  You were on the right track with a lot of your suggestions.  If you want to put something in your answer that explicitly mentions the C library needs to look for the file using the absolute directory, I'll mark this as accepted, as I feel that's the part that's likely to be the most useful to others in the future.

Comment: I completed my explanation as asked :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your first attempt is that you are passing a URL to a library function that expects a path. Try:

```
NSURL *docs = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSString *docsPath = docs.path;
const char *dir = [docsPath UTF8String];
myLibraryEntryPoint(dir,(int)[docsPath length]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was having a similar issue. I have a library in C from where I need to read-write files.

I wrote the code below to find the path to the Documents folder of the app:

```
char path[256] = {0};
strcpy(path, getenv("HOME"));
strcpy(path, "/Documents/file.txt");
FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
```